# Scraping results displayed across multiple pages from a `.aspx` site

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape this site:

[website address](http://www.occeweb.com/MOEAsearch/index.aspx)

If I manually search for `A`, I see the results spread across multiple pages but when I try to fetch the results using my script below, I get the results from the first page repeatedly:

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.occeweb.com/MOEAsearch/index.aspx'

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
for page in range(1,3):
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['txtSearch'] = 'A'
    payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'gvResults'
    payload['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = f'Page${page}'
    res = session.post(url,data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select("#gvResults tr")[1:2]:
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("td")]
        print(data)
```

***How can I get the results from other pages as well?***

Comment: You need the __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTVALIDATION from the new response and you also need to set __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem happens at below line

```py
payload = {i['name']: i.get('value', '') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
```

What happens when your are doing the 2nd page search, it sends an extra payload of `btnSearch`, which cause it to become a search operation instead of a next page operation

Well the fix is quite simple, below is the updated code

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.occeweb.com/MOEAsearch/index.aspx'

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
for page in range(1,3):
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['txtSearch'] = 'A'
    payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'gvResults'
    payload['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = f'Page${page}'
    if page > 1:
       payload.pop('btnSearch')
    res = session.post(url,data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select("#gvResults tr")[1:2]:
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("td")]
        print(data)
```